# How to clone/copy the value of several input inside in one single input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I need this for my school project.

I want JAVASCRIPT to copy/Clone the values of 4 or 5 input fields, when typing content inside of them into one single input.

**this is the input that must collect all values:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="mainInput" name="main" value="" />
```

**This is the rest inputs**

```
<input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" value="info1" />
<input type="text" id="input2" name="input2" value="hello World" />
<input type="text" id="input3" name="input3" value="my SECOND" />
<input type="text" id="input4" name="input4" value="sure!" />
```

**So in the final step, the result must be this:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="mainInput" name="main" value="info1hello Worldmy SECONDsure!" />
```

PS this must happen without any submit buttons... There is a option called **onFocus** in JS.

So any ideas?

Comment: We don't do homework here.

Comment: Start with JS event handlers - you already know which one you need `onfocus`

Comment: :) nice try! that's not homework!

Comment: You can read about $.each function - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: do you want to copy the values when you press a button, or do you want them copied in real time while you are typing in the other inputs ?

Comment: in real time while you are typing in the other inputs

Comment: You say "I need this for my school project", so it's like homework ;). You need to add a trigger on the `onChange` event for each input you want to concatenate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[type="text"]').keydown(function () {
    $('#mainInput').val($('#input1').val() + $('#input2').val() + $('#input3').val() + $('#input4').val())
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Nqu8k/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method and works fine jsfiddle

```
<input type="text" class="testvalues" id="input1" name="input1" value="info1" />
<input type="text" class="testvalues" id="input2" name="input2" value="hello World" />
<input type="text" class="testvalues" id="input3" name="input3" value="my SECOND" />
<input type="text" class="testvalues" id="input4" name="input4" value="sure!" />
<input type="hidden" id="mainInput" name="main" value="" />

 $('.testvalues').on('keyup',function(){    
      var txtfirst=$('#input1').val();
      var txtsecond=$('#input2').val();
      var txtthird=$('#input3').val();
      var txtfourth=$('#input4').val();

      $('#mainInput').val(txtfirst +" "+ txtsecond +" "+ txtthird +" "+ txtfourth );

});
```

Look at fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/HGu5M/22/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="text"]').change(function () {
    $('#mainInput').val($('#input1').val() + $('#input2').val() + $('#input3').val() + $('#input4').val());
})
```